# How to disabled ripple effect in TabRow or Tab in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to use the TabRow, but when I click the background has a ripple effect that I do not want. Is there a way to change this? I have the Tab's selectedContectColor equal to the same background color of the page, but I still see a white ripple effect.

```
TabRow(
   modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp),
   selectedTabIndex = selectedIndex,
   indicator = { tabPositions ->
      TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
       modifier = Modifier.customTabIndicatorOffset(
         currentTabPosition = tabPositions[lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex]
         tabWidths[lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex]
       ),
         color = RED
      )
   },
   backgroundColor = BLACK
) {
    tabList.forEachIndexed{ index, tab ->
     val selected = (selectedIndex == index)
     Tab(
      modifier = Modifier
// Have tried different solutions here where there is a .clickable
// and the indication = null, and set interactionSource = remember{  
//MutableInteractionSource()}
      selected = selected,
      selectedContentColor = BLACK,
      onClick = { 
         animateScrollToItem(selectedIndex)
      },
      text = {
        Text("Text Code")
      }
     )

}

}
```

You can see in these docs that the selectedContentColor affects the ripple

[image: Tab Docs]

[image: More docs]

[image: More docs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ripple is implemented in a `selectable` modifier defined inside the `Tab`.

You can't disable it but you can change the appearance of the ripple that is based on a `RippleTheme`. You can define a custom `RippleTheme` and apply to your composable with the `LocalRippleTheme`.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
    //..TabRow()
}

private object NoRippleTheme : RippleTheme {
    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Unspecified

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
}
```

Comment: I have been trying this solution... It works for Android 11 but not in Android 13, any idea why ?

Comment: yep, still not working on android 13

Comment: not working API 33

Answer (score 1):

Setting an empty interaction source seemed to do the trick for me, I did away with the ripple effect altogether:

```
Tab(
    ...
    interactionSource = object : MutableInteractionSource {
        override val interactions: Flow<Interaction> = emptyFlow()

        override suspend fun emit(interaction: Interaction) {}

        override fun tryEmit(interaction: Interaction) = true
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The shimmer effect is handled by the indication property.
Put it inside the clickable section.

You can create an extension function

```
inline fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(crossinline onClick: ()->Unit): Modifier = composed {
    clickable(indication = null,
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
        onClick()
    }
}
```

then simply replace Modifier.clickable {} with Modifier.noRippleClickable {}

Comment: but a Tab uses the onClick = {}, not the Modifier.clickable. I have tried Modifier.clickable = {} and leaving onClick blank, this results in the tab not being clickable at all.

Comment: Did you try {
indication = null,
interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

Comment: Yes, let me update and add source code

Comment: as you can see, the Ripple in a TAB() is affected by the SelectedContentColor